# How do i search github for a particular and exact term?

Tags: github

Let's say i want to search a repo for

`def fc`

When i type that in, I get hits for "def" and hits for "fc" and I have no idea what order they're in.

If I search for

"def fc"

then it gets a little better, I get hits where i have "def" and then a space, or brackets, or other non-words, and then "fc". This still isn't what I want though - I just want "def" and then a space and then "fc".

It gets worse if I try to search for html - searching for

```
"<input"
```

only yields the word input, which can get quite heavy, and this gets worse if I search for

```
"<input type="text""
```

because now i have no idea how the " works. I looked at the imposing github search help page, https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/ but to no avail.

Comment: This would be amazing - especially with very large complex repos.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub can't do exact searches.  Clone the repo locally and use `git grep "def fc"`

More about GitHub searching [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search).

Answer (score 0):

Since Dec. 2021, you can search for the symbol `fc` (exact match), for a [limited set of supported languages](https://cs.github.com/about/faq#languages).
(As of Dec. 2021:  C#, Python, Go, Java, JavaScript, TypeScript, PHP, Protocol Buffers, Ruby, and Rust)

You must do your search, for now, on [**`cs.github.com`**](https://cs.github.com/about).

> ### [Improving GitHub code search](https://github.blog/2021-12-08-improving-github-code-search/)
>
> (from [Pavel Avgustinov](https://github.com/p0))
>
> Refine your results using filters like `language:`, `path:`, `extension:`, and Boolean operators (`OR`, `NOT`).
> Search for definitions of a symbol with `symbol:`.

Symbol search is based on parsing your code using the open source [Tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter).

See [Symbol qualifier](https://cs.github.com/about/syntax#symbol)

In your case, for instance:

```
language:javascript symbol:fc
```