What factors contribute to the inclusion of items in exact string search results that do not actually contain the specified exact string?
I sought to identify discussions containing the ID of a Docker container by using the exact string 'micropython/unix.'
To ensure accuracy when indicating that I have conducted a search for similar discussions, I entered the phrase in double quotes: '"micropython/unix".' This resulted in the following URL: https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions?discussions_q=is%3Aopen+%22micropython%2Funix%22.
However, the resulting set predominantly features items that include either 'micropython' or 'unix,' rather than the complete specified string. Attempts to escape the '/' using `/' or '//' did not improve the results.
I observed similar outcomes when attempting an advanced query.
Could you please provide the correct search syntax for this query? Additionally, it would be beneficial if it were applicable across all of GitHub.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132067/how-do-i-search-github-for-a-particular-and-exact-term this is not possible

This question is similar to: How to search on GitHub to get exact string matches, including special characters. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
